# Finding the values of all of the checked checkboxes in php

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox

Hi so have form with a vote and what i want to do is what ever options they tick, when they click submit it the posts all the values of the check boxes ticked to the same page allowed me to echo them

i have tried just doing this

> if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
>   $list = $_POST['vote'];
>   echo $list;
>   }

but that only echos the last value selected

Thanks,
Ben

ok so i have a fix by changing the name to an array but i got a problem because i used javascript functions like this

> checkAll(document.form.vote)

so what do i change it to?

Comment: Not familiar with PHP, but if all checkboxes have the same name `vote` the browser should send all checked values as comma separated string to the server. Post your HTML please so we can have a look..

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Answer (score 2):

When you name the inputs you can give it a name like `name="checkboxes[]"` and that will throw it in an array when it posts to the next page. Hope that helps!

Comment: ok the problem is i have a javascript function like this checkAll(document.form.vote) so what would it be changed to, to compensate for renaming the boxes?

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/8x4Yw/ maybe that will help. You can pretty much just grab the checkboxes by name using getElementsByName('checkboxes[]')

Answer (score 2):

In your form set name attribut like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vote[]" />
```

Then you can:

```
foreach($_POST['vote'] as $vote){
echo $vote;
}
```

Comment: ok the problem is i have a javascript function like this checkAll(document.form.vote) so what would it be changed to, to compensate for renaming the boxes?